How to bind the run command with the C# Devkit extension in vscode?
Binding an unused key combination to "csdevkit.debug.noDebugFileLaunch" and using it creates an error "No C# project currently loaded..." while clicking on the "Run project associated with this file" executes the run command on the project correctly. Any ideas?

I've used the "terminal-command-keys" extension to make a "dotnet run" in the meantime.
